# Apache error logs flooded with valid SQL queries

Tags: php, apache, logging

Recently, I switched over to a Debian 7 VPS and set up my Apache configurations and website files. I was previously on an Ubuntu server and this did not happen on there.

After I set up everything, I decided to look at my Apache error logs for the heck of it.  Instead of a small error file, I saw a 100 mb+ file that was constantly increasing at a high rate. Apparently, every single query that was being run on the web server was for some reason being recorded in my Apache error log. ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H829E.png) -- Please excuse the white/black outs. I assure you there are no SQL errors in my queries, since rows are still being inserted.)

Is there a configuration option in PHP/Apache that got switched on for this to happen?

My website relies on MySQL 5, PHP 5.4, and Apache 2.2.

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. what filename is the log? What does your PHP error log state? Can you show some of the lines of code which the log refers to?

Comment: The log is located in /var/log/apache2/error_domain.com.log

Comment: Here is a snippet of code: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/f14CPZS.png) The database wrapper I use is called [NotORM](http://www.notorm.com/), which is basically a wrapper for PDO.

Comment: Go throug the wrapper files and check for error_log function, you may find it